# Spark Aggregatebykey partitioner order

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

If I apply a hash partitioner to Spark's aggregatebykey function, i.e. `myRDD.aggregateByKey(0, new HashPartitioner(20))(combOp, mergeOp)`

Does myRDD get repartitioned first before it's key/value pairs are aggregated using combOp and mergeOp? Or does myRDD go through combOp and mergeOp first and the resulting RDD is repartitioned using the HashPartitioner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aggregateByKey` applies map side aggregation before eventual shuffle. Since every partition is processed sequentially the only operation that is applied in this phase is initialization (creating `zeroValue`) and `combOp`. A goal of `mergeOp` is to combine aggregation buffers so it is not used before shuffle.

If input RDD is a `ShuffledRDD` with the same partitioner as requested for `aggregateByKey` then data is not shuffled at all and data is aggregated locally using `mapPartitions`.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so what is mapPartitions mapping? The combOp?

Comment: @foboi1122 Yes, combOp.